# The word: Downplay

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I'm in situation where I got rejected during the first interview, and subsequently got the offer. It was lucky that the manager appreciated my initiative of an uninvited walked-in to request a reconsideration, which resulted a second interview, thereafter an Offer.

However, the basic salary is low and probation period is long. I feel that I've "downplayed" as I'm the rejected one. I feel that they are not treating me as someone who is competent for the job.Thus, do not want to pay an equal wages. At the same time they may not have a good expectation from me.

Can I use the word Downplay in this manner? As I noticed it usually applies to thing I.e The report downplays the seriousness of the event. Is there a better word to describe my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO.

Downplay is usually used in the context of politics and other kinds of strategies.

eg. Since John's scandal is all over the newspapers at this point, he might want to downplay the effect of it in his future campaign.

OR

eg. Athletes often downplay their injuries. (reference:http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downplay)

**YOU HAVE TO HAVE A PROBLEM IN THE FIRST PLACE!** Then downplay can be a strategy for you.

Recommended usage in your case:

looked down upon/undervalued

I felt I am being looked down upon/undervalued, or in a sense rejected by the manager.

Note: devalue/depreciate is not correct, because they are used to describe money not people. undervalued, however, has been used for people, such as professional football or basketball players who get paid for playing sports.

Answer (score 1):

*[Downplay](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/downplay#Verb)*, meaning  “To de-emphasize; to present or portray as less important or consequential”, is not the correct verb for the situation.

Consider instead the following verbs and some of the words appearing in the definitions [from wiktionary] for them:
• *[devalue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/devalue#Verb)*, “To lower or remove the value of something” [eg, “They have devalued my services”]
• *[undervalue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/undervalue#Verb)*, “To underestimate, or assign too low a value to” [eg, “They have undervalued me”]
• *[deprecate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprecate#Verb)*, “To belittle or express disapproval of” [eg, “They have deprecated me”]

You might also say you have *[underbid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underbid#Verb)*, using that verb in its card-playing sense:

> (bridge) To bid less than the full value of a hand of cards